# Why was my reputation reset?

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-graph

My reputation was reset a while ago. I had nearly 50 reputation, but it got reset back to zero. My achievements were reset as well; everything related to reputation was reset back to 0 zero. Stack Overflow says I have 136 and 95 reputation at the same time. [I tried doing this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309846) but it didn't work, nothing happened. Why did this happen? Can it be fixed?

[image]

Comment: There was something weird with your account (some mod things were going haywire). A CM found your second account and merged it into this account, which seems to have fixed that oddity at any rate. I show you have 95 reputation in all locations now

Comment: Thanks! when will my acc update?

Comment: Is something still broken? I don't see anything else obviously wrong

Comment: My accounts were merged but my reputation graph is the same.

Comment: The graph just appears out of sync. I checked the mod tooling and it confirms your rep is 95. The weirdness probably caused it but that graph is not real-time

Comment: then what happened to the reputation I lost?

Comment: You posted a rude answer on Dec 25. That's the only reputation loss I see https://stackoverflow.com/users/14586140/user14586140?tab=reputation

Comment: @user14586140 - You should give the system 24 hours.  The graph isn't real time.  You have 95 reputation on SO.

Comment: I see 105 as Stack Overflow and still see 95 at meta. Things are a wee bit out of synch, but I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @user4581301 - 6 hours later and it's insync

Comment: @Machavity the graph still isn't in sync. the graph is still out of sync and its been 2 days https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuA8D.png

Comment: I de-tagged the completed status since something else is still wrong here

Comment: The graph still appears to be out of sync.

Comment: @41686d6564  it is a known bug (for 6 to 8 years now) that the -100 penalties due to red flags are not taken into account in the graph.

Comment: @rene Yeah but I think something else is wrong. The OP's graph shows 235 while the actual rep is 196 (not 135), which (I assume) is why Machavity said he removed the [status-completed] tag as per the comment above mine.